# System Exception: error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, uber-api

I am trying to get the user activity from uber. Below are the codes

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Callback(string code)
{
    var auth = new AuthenticationClient();
    await auth.WebServerAsync(_clientId, _clientSecret, _callbackUrl, code);

    Session["ApiVersion"] = auth.ApiVersion;
    Session["AccessToken"] = auth.AccessToken;
    Session["RefreshToken"] = auth.RefreshToken;

    var client = new UberClient(TokenTypes.Access, auth.AccessToken, "v1", new HttpClient());

    var userActivity = await client.UserActivityAsync(); //error here
    var user = await client.UserAsync();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

This is the error trace

> [Exception: error]    Uber.d__19`1.MoveNext() +1738
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +24    Uber.d__f.MoveNext() +691    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +24    Web.Controllers.<Callback>d__0.MoveNext() in d:\TDS\uber-sdk-for-net-master-1\samples\Web\Controllers\LoginController.cs:42
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   +21    System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted(Task task)
>   +61    System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +114
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +66
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +47
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +102
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
>   +117    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
>   +323    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +47
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +102
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +50
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
>   +72    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +185
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +42
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +56
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +40
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +70
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +59
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +40
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +62
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +59
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +40    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +39
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +39
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +70
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +59
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +40
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +40    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +38
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +129

Can someone kindly explain to me what is the error? Thanks in advance. The codes is originally from [WadeWegner Uber SDK](https://github.com/wadewegner/uber-sdk-for-net/blob/master/samples/Web/Controllers/LoginController.cs).

Comment: Important information is missing. If `UserActivityAsync` fails, you should check *it* for problems. What is the method supposed to do when it fails, eg due to an authentication error? Did you try debugging? What is the exception *message*? The type of exception? Inner Exception? Please wrap the code in an exception handler and add proper exception logging

Comment: The authentication is already passed successfully but UserActivityAsync just fail...when i catch the error, this is shown "An error occurred while processing your request.".